# Is there a way to use serializedObject in EditorWindow script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a script with a List :

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class Test : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
```

And when using only Editor script not EditorWindow I could do :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
public class TestTriggerEditor : Editor
{
    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
    }
```

But now I want to do it in a EditorWindow script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestingEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    [MenuItem("Testing/Editor")]
    private static void ConversationsSystem()
    {
        const int width = 340;
        const int height = 420;

        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        GetWindow<TestingEditorWindow>().position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
    }
}
```

But I'm getting error on the line inside the OnGUI :

```
_conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
```

The error is on the serializedObject :

The name 'serializedObject' does not exist in the current context

If I'm changing it to SerializedObject I'm getting error :

An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'SerializedObject.FindProperty(string)'

I tried to change the _conversations to be static but it didn't help.

I also tried to make :

```
SerializedObject serializedObject = new SerializedObject(
```

But not sure how to work with it. Why in the Editor script it was working fine but in the EditorWindow it's not ?

Comment: @RetiredNinja  First of all `EditorWindow` inherits from `ScriptableObject` which already **is** serializeable. Second this doesn't change the fact that EditorWindow simply has no such property. Reason see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56122933/7111561)

Answer (score 4):

The difference is that [`Editor`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor.html)

1. as you can see the  is clearly related to one certain type in

   ```c#
   [CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
   ```
2. further, and more important, it is the inspector for **one certain instance** of that type attached to the currently selected GameObject. Therefore you can acccess the `serializedObject` instance of that `MonoBehaviour` (or `ScriptableObject`)

   see [`Editor.serializedObject`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Editor-serializedObject.html)

   > A `SerializedObject` representing the object or objects being inspected.

---

On the other side [`EditorWindow`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorWindow.html) is **not** related to a certain type **nor** to a certain instance or GameObject but is just a window that will be opened. You can say it lives in a kind of `static` environment (instead of the instanced one like the `Editor`).

Therefore there simply is no `serializedObject` it would be related to => It doesn't have such a property.

---

Using `SerializedObject` ofcourse doesn't work as this is a type not an instance and the method [`FindProperty`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject.FindProperty.html) is not static but requires an instance as the error message tries to tell you.

I don't want to sound bad but if that is is something you don't understand yet than you should immediately stop worrying about EditorScripting and get some refreshments in basic c# coding and/or object-oriented programming in general.

---

You *could* use the [constructor](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SerializedObject-ctor.html)

```c#
var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(referenceToTest);
```

**if** you somehow can get a reference to one certain instance of `Test`.

You could do that for example using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html)

```c#
var referenceToTest = FindObjectOfType<Test>();
if(! referenceToTest) return;
```

To get the first active and enabled `Test` instance from the current Scene.

Or e.g. use the [`Selection.transforms`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Selection-transforms.html)

```c#
var selected = Selection.transforms;
Test referenceToTest;
foreach (var item in selected)
{
    referenceToTest = item.GetComponent<Test>();
    if(referenceToTest) break;
}

if(! referenceToTest) return;
```

to get the first encounter of `Test` from the selected objects in the scene hierarchy window.

---

As alternative you could open that `EditorWindow` from the Inspector of `Test` instead of openening it from the `static` menu bar and pass in the `MonoBehaviour` reference. (Passing in the `serializedObject` directly would only work if the Inspector stays opened since the serializedObject instance is probably destroyed along with the `TestEditor` when the GameObject is not selected anymore)

```c#
[CustomEditor(typeof(Test))]
public class TestEditor : Editor
{
    public override void OnInpectorGUI ()
    {
        // Draw the default inspector
        DrawDefaultInspector();

        EditorGUILayout.Space();

        // Add a button for opening the EditorWindow and pass in the reference
        if(GUILayout.Button("Open EditorWindow"))
        {
            TestEditorWindow.ConversationsSystem((Test) target);
        }
    }
}
```

And received and store the reference in

```c#
public class TestingEditorWindow : EditorWindow
{
    const int width = 340;
    const int height = 420;

    private SerializedProperty _conversations;

    private Test currentTestInstance;

    public static void ConversationsSystem(Test testInstance)
    { 
        var x = (Screen.currentResolution.width - width) / 2;
        var y = (Screen.currentResolution.height - height) / 2;

        var window = GetWindow<TestingEditorWindow>();

        window.position = new Rect(x, y, width, height);

        window.currentTestInstance = testInstance;
    }

    private void OnGUI()
    {
        if(! currentTestInstance)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.HelpBox("No Test instance selected!", MessageType.Error);
            return;
        }

        var serializedObject = new SerializedObject(currentTestInstance);

        _conversations = serializedObject.FindProperty("conversations");
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warranty but I hope the idea gets clear*

Answer (score 3):

Ran into the same problem. I didn't expect the below to work, but it did.

```
public class TestingEditorWindow : EditorWindow {
  [SerializeField]
  private string exampleField;

  [SerializeField]
  private List<int> exampleField2;

  private SerializedObject serializedObject;

  private void OnEnable() {
    serializedObject = new SerializedObject(this);
  }

  private void OnGUI() {
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("exampleField");
    EditorGUILayout.PropertyField(serializedObject.FindProperty("exampleField2");
    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
  }

  [MenuItem("Testing/Editor")]
  private static void OpenEditorWindow() {
    GetWindow<TestingEditorWindow>();
  }
}
```

The magic is that creating a `SerializedObject` of the `EditorWindow` is permitted, and works just like how you expect it to work for normal `MonoBehaviour` scripts. But given that `SerializedObject` actually inherits from `ScriptableObject`, I guess this is no surprise.